# access/modify an object inside of a function | javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

lets say I have a function - object constructor:

```
var constructor = function(name, surname, town){
    return {
        Name: name,
        Surname: surname,
        Town: town
    }
};
```

Now I can create a new obj like this:

```
var peter = constructor("Peter", "Jameson", "London");
```

and I can add new properties to my new object `peter` using dot notation like this:

```
peter.phoneNumber = 856687;
```

My question is: Is it possible to add more properties to my constructor using dot/bracket notation when the object in the constructor/function has no var?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you mean by modifying the code of `constructor`, or by doing something at runtime?

Comment: FYI: `species` is not passed to the function. And yes, please clarify your question. Show us what do you want to achive, how you want to use the sing dot/bracket notation

Comment: I would like to modify the code of constructor using dot notation (if its possible in this case), e.g. I would like to add more properties to my constructor. If the code was like this:

'code' var constructor = function(name, surname, town){
    var person = {
        Name: name,
        Surname: species,
        Town: town
    };
return person
}; 'code'

then I guess I could modify my constructor like this:
{constructor.person.phoneNumber = 554457;

but in my original code constructor has no var inside so I cant taget obj

Comment: Well, no; if you had a `var person` inside the constructor, you couldn't do `constructor.person...` either. Why do you want to do this on the *constructor*, when it seems pretty clear that you should be adding your phone number to the *instance* instead?!

Comment: Incidentally, terminology-wise your function is more of a *factory* than a *constructor* - usually the word "constructor" is applied to functions intended to be called with `new`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification :) But if we get back to the original code (without var person) so there is no way to modify that code outside of the function?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to modify the behavior of `constructor` at runtime. You've said:

> I would like to modify the code of constructor using dot notation (if its possible in this case), e.g. I would like to add more properties to my constructor. If the code was like this:
>
> ```
> var constructor = function(name, surname, town){
>     var person = { Name: name, Surname: species, Town: town };
>     return person;
> };
> ```
>
> ...then I guess I could modify my constructor like this: `{constructor.person.phoneNumber = 554457;` but in my original code constructor has no var inside so I cant taget obj

As @deceze pointed out, no, you couldn't do that even if `constructor` had a variable in it; that variable is entirely private to the function, it's not exposed as a property of `constructor`.

The only way<sup>1</sup> to modify `constructor`'s behavior *at runtime* is to wrap it in a new function, like this:

```
(function() {
    var original = constructor;
    constructor = function() {
        var obj = original.apply(this, arguments);
        obj.phoneNumber = 554457;
        return obj;
    };
})();
```

That calls the original version with all of the arguments it receives (and the same `this`), then adds the additional property, and returns it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Okay, *technically*, you could decompile it with `toString` (on browsers that support it; support is now required as of ES5, so it's pretty good), use text manipulation to change its contents, then use `new Function` to turn it back into a function and assign the result to `constructor`, but A) It's a really bad idea, and B) The function would lose its context, and so if it relied on closing over any variables that aren't globals, it would stop working (hence [A]).

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for, thank you !